# Python CSV - Need to Group and Calculate values based on one key

Tags: python, csv

I have a simple 3 column csv file that i need to use python to group each row based on one key, then average the values for another key and return them. File is standard csv format, set up as so;

```
ID, ZIPCODE, RATE
1, 19003, 27.50
2, 19003, 31.33
3, 19083, 41.4
4, 19083, 17.9
5, 19102, 21.40
```

So basically what I need to do is calculate the average rate col[2] for each unique zipcode col[1] in that file and return the results. So get average rate for all records in 19003, 19083, and so on.

I've looked at using csv module and reading the file into a dictionary, then sorting the dict based on unique values in the zipcode col but can't seem to make any progress.

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: "I've looked at using csv module and reading the file into a dictionary, then sorting the dict based on unique values in the zipcode col but can't seem to make any progress."  All good so far.  Post the code you're having problems with.  When in doubt, break things down into smaller steps, and code those small pieces first.  Please post code.

Comment: Possible silly question, but are all the comma delimited values on one line, or is it one line per row of 3 columns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've documented some steps to help clarify things:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# a dictionary whose value defaults to a list.
data = defaultdict(list)
# open the csv file and iterate over its rows. the enumerate()
# function gives us an incrementing row number
for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(open('data.csv', 'rb'))):
    # skip the header line and any empty rows
    # we take advantage of the first row being indexed at 0
    # i=0 which evaluates as false, as does an empty row
    if not i or not row:
        continue
    # unpack the columns into local variables
    _, zipcode, level = row
    # for each zipcode, add the level the list
    data[zipcode].append(float(level))

# loop over each zipcode and its list of levels and calculate the average
for zipcode, levels in data.iteritems():
    print zipcode, sum(levels) / float(len(levels))
```

Output:

```
19102 21.4
19003 29.415
19083 29.65
```

Comment: @samplebias, @cmaynard I used this on my data, and it returns `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`. Any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: @Ana, You probably have two many items in a row, it expects three here: `_, zipcode, level = row`

Comment: @cmaynard yes, I have a big table with multiple columns. But I just want to group them in a similar way to this question.

Comment: if I want to group by multi values instead of just one zipcode, What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Usually if I have to do complicate elaboration I use csv to load the rows in a table of a relational DB (sqlite is the fastest way) then I use the standard sql methods to extract data and calculate average values:

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
import sqlite3

data = """1,19003,27.50
2,19003,31.33
3,19083,41.4
4,19083,17.9
5,19102,21.40
"""

f = StringIO(data)
reader = csv.reader(f)

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''create table data (ID text, ZIPCODE text, RATE real)''')
conn.commit()

for e in reader:
    e[2] = float(e[2])
    c.execute("""insert into data
          values (?,?,?)""", e)

conn.commit()

c.execute('''select ZIPCODE, avg(RATE) from data group by ZIPCODE''')
for row in c:
    print row
```