# Python CSV - Need to sum up values in a column grouped by value in another column

Tags: python, csv

I have data in a csv that needs to be parsed. It looks like:

```
Date, Name, Subject, SId, Mark
2/2/2013, Andy Cole, History, 216351, 98
2/2/2013, Andy Cole, Maths, 216351, 87
2/2/2013, Andy Cole, Science, 217387, 21
2/2/2013, Bryan Carr, Maths, 216757, 89
2/2/2013, Carl Jon, Botany, 218382, 78
2/2/2013, Bryan Carr, Biology, 216757, 27
```

I need to have Sid as the key and sum up all the values in mark column using this key.
The output would be something like:

```
Sid     Mark
216351  185
217387   21
216757  116
218382   78
```

I do not have to write the output on a file. I will just need it when I execute the python file.
This is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328971/python-csv-need-to-group-and-calculate-values-based-on-one-key). 
How should that be changed to skip the columns in between?

Comment: I do not understand the use of underscores in the first answer. I have tried using the same code with as many underscores for all the columns I wish to ignore.

Comment: Using an underscore as a variable just means "I don't care about this variable". You can use actual names, like `Date, Name, Subject, SId, Mark = row` if you want, and then just never reference the names, if that helps you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the concept of a histogram. Use a `defaultdict(int)` from `collections` and iterate through your rows. Use the 'Sid' value as key for the dict and add the 'Mark' value to the current value.

The defaultdict of type int makes sure that if a key is not existing so far its value becomes initialized with 0.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = [t.strip() for t in line.split(",")]
        try:
            sid = int(tokens[3])
            mark = int(tokens[4])
        except ValueError:
            continue
        d[sid] += mark

print d
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {217387: 21, 216757: 116, 218382: 78, 216351: 185})
```

You can change the parsing part to anything else (e.g. use `csvreader` or perform other validations). The key point here is to use a the `defaultdict(int)` and to update it like so:

```
d[sid] += mark
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to adapt the solution in the link you provided, you can modify which rows to unpack.

Here is an idea (adapted from samplebias's solution in OP's link):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# a dictionary whose value defaults to a list.
data = defaultdict(list)
# open the csv file and iterate over its rows. the enumerate()
# function gives us an incrementing row number
for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(open('data.csv', 'rb'))):
    # skip the header line and any empty rows
    # we take advantage of the first row being indexed at 0
    # i=0 which evaluates as false, as does an empty row
    if not i or not row:
        continue
    # unpack the columns into local variables


    _, _, _, SID, mark = row#### <--- HERE, change what you unpack


    # for each SID, add the mark the list
    data[SID].append(float(mark))

# loop over each SID and its list of mark and calculate the sum
for zipcode, mark in data.iteritems():
    print SID, sum(mark)
```

Comment: This would be simpler with `DictReader`. Then you don't need to skip the header, and you can just do `SID, mark = row['SId'], row['Mark']` instead of having to explain how to skip columns.

Comment: The OP did ask "How should that be changed to skip the columns in between?"

Comment: I didn't realize that the "that" he's referring to is an answer that expands rows in the exact same way you're doing it. In that case, this is a reasonable answer… except that if the OP didn't understand "that" well enough to know what to do himself, he won't understand this any better…

Answer (score -1):

First, to parse the CSV, use the `csv` module:

```
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    data = csv.DictReader(f)
```

Now, you want to group them by Sid. You can do this by sorting, then using `groupby`. (Sorting is unnecessary if equal values will always be contiguous.)

```
    siddata = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter('SId'))
    sidgroups = itertools.groupby(siddata, operator.itemgetter('SId'))
```

Now, you want to sum the values in each group:

```
    for key, group in sidgroups:
        print('{}\t{}'.format(key, sum(int(value['Mark']) for value in group))
```

---

Alternatively, you could just write it all to a database and let SQLite figure out how to do it for you:

```
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f, sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as db:
    db.execute('CREATE TABLE data (SId, Mark)')
    db.executemany('INSERT INTO data VALUES (:SId, :Mark)', csv.DictReader(f))
    cursor = db.execute('SELECT SId, SUM(Mark) AS Mark FROM data GROUP BY SId')
    for row in cursor:
        print('{}\t{}'.format(row))
```