# Trouble with csv reading file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, dataframe

Write a function named "quantities_owned" that takes one parameter that is a string representing a filename that contains all the trades made by your company throughout the year and returns a dictionary containing the quantity of each stock owned by the company by ticker symbol. Each row of CSV file will contain a single trade in the format "buy_or_sell,quantity,ticker,date" where buy_or_sell is either the string "buy" or "sell", quantity is an integer representing the number of shares traded, ticker is a string representing the ticker symbol being traded, and date is the date of the trade in the format YYYY-MM-DD. This function will return a dictionary with ticker symbols as keys, and the number of shares of each ticker symbol owned as values as integers.

For example if the input file contains:

```
buy,1700,XOM,2015-01-26
buy,1900,AAPL,2015-02-13
sell,700,XOM,2015-02-17
buy,700,AAPL,2015-02-17
```

Then the output would be {'AAPL': 2600, 'XOM':1000}. 
(My code below)

```
import csv
def quantities_owned(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        dicti = {}
        for row in reader:
            dicti[str(row[2])] = int(row[1])
    return dicti
```

I am having difficulty with trying to differentiate the two values in the key buy_or_sell. How would I attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: Print out the value of 'row' so that you know what it contains, then decide how to use that information. Also, why have you written "if row[2] == row[2]"?

Comment: I wanted to put similar keys together with the same tinker symbol.

Comment: How does "if row[2] == row[2]" help you to do that? It's always true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python CSV - Need to sum up values in a column grouped by value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712405/python-csv-need-to-sum-up-values-in-a-column-grouped-by-value-in-another-colum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple adjustment to your already written code:

```
import csv
def quantities_owned(filename):
    tran = {'buy': 1, 'sell': -1}
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        dicti = {}
        for row in reader:
            if row[2] in dicti:
                dicti[row[2]] += tran[row[0]] * int(row[1])
            else:
                dicti[row[2]] = tran[row[0]] * int(row[1])
    return dicti
```

Alternatively, use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
def quantities_owned(filename):
    tran = {'buy': 1, 'sell': -1}
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        dicti = defaultdict(int)
        for row in reader:
            dicti[row[2]] += tran[row[0]] * int(row[1])
    return dicti
```

Comment: Look over your code. I am getting an incorrect input with your code when using the input I stated above.

Comment: @Anonymous Fixed. I missed the part about buy/sell.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas `groupby`, then do `to_dict` for converting back to dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('filename.txt',header=None)
df.loc[df[0]=='sell',1]=-df.loc[df[0]=='sell',1]
print(df.groupby(2)[1].sum().to_dict())
```

Output:

```
{'AAPL': 2600, 'XOM': 1000}
```

I used `loc` for making the values that are sell to negative so when summing it will subtract that

[`pandas` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)

I Use `pandas` because regular python is too hard for this, will take long time (slow), and long code (inefficient), so do pandas which is super fast, and super easy, (little code)

As everyone says in the comments, "How does `if row[2] == row[2]` help you to do that? It's always true. ", that's the main issue.

Now `pandas` has to be your friend :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without using pandas or any external libraries.

```
results = {}
with open(filename) as f:

    body = f.read().split("\n")
    for entry in body:
        splittedEntry = entry.split(",")
        if splittedEntry[3] in results:
            results[splittedEntry[3]] += int(splittedEntry[1])
        else:
            results[splittedEntry[3] = int(splittedEntry[1])
```

I haven't had a chance to test this yet, but this should at least demonstrate the general concept.