# Grouping data in csv file by month

Tags: python, csv

i am trying to create a simple interface that allow user to choose a csv files and then display the data by month.so far this is the code i came out with

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
import datetime
import random
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from itertools import accumulate

root = Tk()
f = Frame(root)
fig=plt.figure(1)
fig2=plt.figure(2)
kit=[]
lau=[]
air=[]
oth=[]
mon=[]
accu=[]
tot=[]

def readCSV():

    del kit[:],lau[:],air[:],oth[:],mon[:],tot[:],accu[:]    

    filename =filedialog.askopenfilename()
    try:
        f = open(filename,"r")
        data=plt.mlab.csv2rec(f,delimiter =",")
        for row in data:
            mon.append(row[0])
            kit.append(row[1])
            lau.append(row[2])
            air.append(row[3])
            oth.append(row[4])
            accu.append(row[5])
            tot.append(row[6])




    except (IOError,UnboundLocalError,IndexError):
        messagebox.showinfo( "Error", "Invalid or file not found")   

def graph():
    #Original Chart
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.clf()
    kitchen=np.array(kit)
    laundry=np.array(lau)
    aircon=np.array(air)
    other=np.array(oth)
    ind=np.arange(11)+0.75
    width=0.75


    p1=plt.bar(ind,kitchen,width,color="cyan")
    p2=plt.bar(ind,laundry,width,color="purple",bottom=kitchen)
    p3=plt.bar(ind,aircon,width,color="green",bottom=kitchen+laundry)
    p4=plt.bar(ind,other,width,color="red",bottom=kitchen+laundry+aircon)


    plt.ylabel("KWH")
    plt.ylim(0,1200)
    datee=[]
    for dt in mon:
        datee.append(dt.strftime("%b/%y"))    
    plt.xticks(ind+width/2,datee,rotation=70)
    fontP = FontProperties()
    fontP.set_size('small')
    plt.title('Actual Monthly Consumption')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.legend((p1[0],p2[0],p3[0],p4[0]),('kitchen','laundry','aircon&heater','other'),'best',prop=fontP)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=c)
    canvas.show()
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=1)
    toolbar.grid(row=2,column=0)
f.grid(row=0,column=0)
#place buttons on the *frame*
var = StringVar()
label = Label( f, textvariable=var,bg="pink")
var.set("Select Database\n(Csv file)")
label.grid(row=0,column=0,ipadx=1,sticky=W)
label.config(height=2,width=15)

b1 =Button(f, text ="Csv\nselector", command = readCSV,bg='cyan')
b1.grid(row=1,column=0,ipadx=1,padx=5)


b2 =Button(f,text="Summary",command=graph,bg='orange')

b2.grid(row=1,column=1,ipadx=1,padx=5)
width =350
height=250
c = Canvas(root, width=width, height=height, bg='gray')


c.grid(row=1,column=0)
```

so far the interface uses csv files sorted by month as such

```
Date,Kitchen,Laundry,Aircon&heater,Others,Accumulative,Total
January/2010,53.887,56.568,395.913,483.293,989.661,989.661
February/2010,49.268,53.590,411.714,409.956,1914.1894,924.528
March/2010,35.089,60.872,324.352,382.285,2716.7877,802.598
April/2010,38.196,36.476,336.091,328.872,3456.4231,739.635
May/2010,48.107,52.376,364.625,349.765,4271.296433,814.873
June/2010,65.747,47.675,306.934,277.734,4969.386833,698.090
July/2010,17.667,34.359,192.912,291.525,5505.849367,536.463
August/2010,12.499,26.983,160.189,168.719,5874.238933,368.390
September/2010,36.865,32.508,257.861,277.923,6479.396,605.157
October/2010,48.199,60.220,315.669,441.461,7344.945233,865.549
November/2010,45.082,41.897,237.124,394.402,8063.449967,718.505
```

But i was told that the file would be this kind of format

```
Date,Total (Kwh),Kitchen_Accumulative(KWh),LaundaryRoom_Accumulative(KWh),Air-Con_Accumulative (KWh),Others (KWh)
1/1/2007,45.817,0.000,0.352,5.880,39.585
2/1/2007,21.154,0.000,0.348,6.562,14.244
3/1/2007,16.901,0.000,0.344,4.765,11.792
4/1/2007,54.324,1.051,7.597,10.896,34.780
5/1/2007,45.223,1.483,0.379,7.602,35.759
6/1/2007,25.140,1.336,0.402,5.678,17.724
7/1/2007,40.794,1.987,8.177,12.810,17.820
8/1/2007,37.356,0.000,0.467,17.547,19.342
9/1/2007,31.151,1.688,4.267,9.790,15.406
10/1/2007,35.913,0.771,4.456,11.012,19.674
11/1/2007,37.587,1.378,2.170,12.415,21.624
12/1/2007,24.355,0.000,0.439,8.276,15.640
13/1/2007,53.114,7.806,2.975,11.341,30.992
14/1/2007,50.130,1.777,4.215,12.975,31.163
15/1/2007,35.811,1.099,2.239,15.163,17.310
16/1/2007,28.107,2.063,0.644,6.583,18.817 
...
```

all the way up to 31/12/2007.

so the user can choose to display the chart either by months(like my code) or days(single month) using an additional 2 button labeled "month" and "days".

my question is,how i do append the data into lists by months so i can either add it up and show 12 month chart or a single month (30 days)? i have absolutely no idea how to read csv files up to certain row.

The first files was easy as all i have to do was to for loop and append them but it obviously doesn't work for the 2nd file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 3):

Things you might need:

- [csv modules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) or [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.9.4) (*If your data contains Unicode data*)
- [itertools.groupby function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Rough pseudocode:

1. Read your csv data into a list
2. Transform that list into groups by using `itertools.groupby` using a key (*your Date(s)*)
3. Anything else you want to do with your data...

Other useful resources:

- [Python CSV - Need to Group and Calculate values based on one key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328971/python-csv-need-to-group-and-calculate-values-based-on-one-key)
- [Python CSV - Need to sum up values in a column grouped by value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712405/python-csv-need-to-sum-up-values-in-a-column-grouped-by-value-in-another-colum)
- [querycsv on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/querycsv)

**Update:** Example of using `itertools.groupby()`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> xs = [
...     (("1", "Sep", "2013"), 123.4),
...     (("15", "Sep", "2013"), 234.0),
...     (("1", "Oct", "2014"), 456.0),
...     (("15", "Oct", "2014"), 778.0),
... ]
>>> group_by_month = lambda x: x[0][1]
>>> groups = groupby(xs, group_by_month)
>>> key, group  = next(groups)
>>> key, list(group)
('Sep', [(('1', 'Sep', '2013'), 123.4), (('15', 'Sep', '2013'), 234.0)])
>>> key, group  = next(groups)
>>> key, list(group)
('Oct', [(('1', 'Oct', '2014'), 456.0), (('15', 'Oct', '2014'), 778.0)])
>>> key, group  = next(groups)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Comment: how do you use itertools.groupby? i couldn't understand any of the examples i found on the web

Comment: @user3555206 See updated response showing a similar example of using ``itertools.groupby`` related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

First create dictionary with months as keys and empty list as values like this:

```
months = {'1' : [], '2': [], ..., '12': []}
```

Then read CSV file line by line (skip first line), split that line with split(',') method
from strings. Then extract month from first element of splited list and add rest of
values to list in your dictionaray like this:

```
months[month].extend(splited_list[1:])
```

Comment: Splitting lines by commas is an exceedingly poor way of handling CSV files and can be quite error prone especially if your CSV data was not properly constructed or uses separators other than , or worse inconsistent use of separators. YOu really should use the ``csv`` modules here or the ``unicodecsv`` module on PyPi if you data has Unicode characters.

Comment: thanks on your comment, I wasn't aware of CSV module and I assumed that CSV data was properly constructed.